# ODBC connection string for multi-tenant HANA database

Tags: vba, excel, connection-string, hana

What will be the connection string that can be used in EXCEL VBA to connect to multi-tenant HANA database ? Currently I am using the string mentioned below but getting `10709 error`:-

```
connectionstring = "Driver=HDBODBC;SERVERNODE=10.20.30.40:30015; DATABASENAME=ABCDE;CS=DBO"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to the tenant you're interested in, you need to provide the correct port number. 
E.g. 30045 if the overall instance no. is 00.

The whole port assignment scheme is explained in detail in the  ["SAP HANA Multitenant Database Containers Operations Guide"](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Multitenant_Database_Containers_en.pdf) chapter **2.9 Connections for Multitenant Database Containers**

Comment: It seems I can connect to a tenant db just by specifying SERVERNODE=<hostname>:<tenant db sql port number>, even if I don't supply the DATABASE connection property. Is this safe? If I know the tenant db port number, why do I need supply the dbname, too?

Comment: I know in the guide you linked it says the DATABASE property method "...is recommended over specifying the specific port for the tenant database", what I'd like to know is if there's a specific reason for favouring one method over the other aside from convenience. Thanks!

Comment: The benefit of using the database name instead of the port is that it allows for changing the port of the database (e.g. when a tenant DB is moved to a server that already has a different tenant DB using the ports) without having to change the meaning of the connection in the application code. The instance number (which drives what ports to use) is an operational detail, that has zero meaning to the clients - except for the connection string. So, avoiding the use of the ports helps with independence from the DB operations.

Comment: That makes sense. I found one instance where the DATABASE method resulted in not being able to make a connection though -- when connecting to a HANA server running on an Azure VM. When I try to just provide the hostname and database name in HANA Studio I can't connect, but when I just provide the hostname:port number (and omit the DATABASE property) I can connect using ODBC Test. Interestingly, if I attempt to connect from another Azure VM I can connect using the DATABASE connection property. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Maybe the port to the system DB/Nameserver is being blocked in this setup. This would probably be a question in its own right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562029/reccomended-method-of-connecting-to-an-sap-hana-tenant-database