# Reccomended method of connecting to an SAP HANA tenant database

Tags: azure, jdbc, odbc, hana

I'm connecting to a SAP HANA tenant database. As I understand it, there are two ways to do this: first, I can specify `<server hostname>:<tenant db sql port>` for the `SERVERNODE` connection property. Second, I can specify `<server hostname>:<system db sql port>` for `SERVERNODE` and also include the `DATABASE` connection property set to `<tenant db name>`. It's recommended to use the second method because it makes operations like moving tenant dbs (i.e. changing sql ports) easier (see "[SAP HANA Multitenant Database Containers Operations Guide](http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_Multitenant_Database_Containers_en.pdf)" section 2.9 Connections for Multitenant Database Containers).

However, I found one instance where the `DATABASE` method resulted in not being able to make a connection while the other (non-recommended method) allowed me to connect -- when connecting to a HANA server running on an Azure VM. When I try to just provide the hostname and database name in HANA Studio I can't connect, but when I just provide the hostname:port number (and omit the DATABASE property) I can connect using ODBC Test. Interestingly, if I attempt to connect from another Azure VM I can connect using the DATABASE connection property. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: As I don't have an AZURE based system at hand, I can only speculate that the ports required to communicate with the SystemDB (in order to find out the ports of the DB you want to connect to) are blocked for requests from outside of AZURE. 
Can you check whether this is the case?

Comment: Azure does block ports by default, so that could very well be it. Does anything other than 3xx13 (where xx is the instance number) need to be open in order to properly communicate with the SystemDB?

Comment: As documented in the Server Installation and Update guide, the following ports are required for *external* communication: 3<instance_no>15 (SQL), 3<instance_no>08 (HTTP via XS classic), 3<instance_no>13 (SystemDB SQL), 3<instance_no>14 (SystemDB HTTP via XS classic). If other components are used, these may require additional ports.

Comment: I think the real problem with SAP is that they are using non-IANA-registered ports on the Internet. The other thing is that they use too many ports (a SAP system occupies hundreds of ports) (IMHO)